# Nagios monitoring nvidia on Windows OS

Tags: windows, nagios, graphics-processing-unit

Can somebody give me advice, about monitoring on Nagios.

How i can monitor GPU temperature on NVidia graphic card, under Windows 2008 R2 OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question is: is there a CLI command that outputs the GPU's temperature? If yes you're done.

Write a script that is run by NRPE which

- runs the command,
- processes its output,
- returns the state you like.

Comment: I find solution.

Nvidia Drivers have NVWMI.

namespace like this Root\CIMV2\**NV**

Then we need find Class - Thermal Probe.

On this class we have temperature.